# Al convertir VARCHAR a DATETIME en otro servidor, aparece: La conversión del tipo de datos nvarchar en datetime produjo un valor fuera de intervalo

Tags: sql, sql-server

Se ha creado un **procedimiento almacenado** en SQL Server, el cual funciona para obtener los eventos de un rango de Fechas. Estos eventos obtenidos se muestran con FullCalendar; el proyecto está en .Net.

**Procedimiento almacenado:**

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_getVisitorsForMonth] 
@FechaInicio VARCHAR(15),
@FechaFin VARCHAR(15)
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT
    v.Id,
    v.NombreVisitante,
    v.NombreEmpresa,
    v.MotivoVisita,
    (SELECT CAST(v.Fecha AS DATETIME) + CAST(v.HoraIngreso AS DATETIME)) HoraIngreso,
    (SELECT CAST(v.Fecha AS DATETIME) + CAST(v.HoraSalida AS DATETIME)) HoraSalida,
    CONCAT(e.Nombre, ' ', e.Apellidos) AS Empleado, 
    a.Nombre as Area,
    v.EstatusID
  FROM Visitas v
  INNER JOIN Empleados e
  ON v.EmpleadoID = e.Id
  INNER JOIN Areas a
  ON v.AreaID = a.Id
  WHERE 
  v.EstatusID = 100 
  AND v.Fecha >= @FechaInicio
  AND v.Fecha <= @FechaFin
END
GO
```

En el **servidor de pruebas** este procedimiento **funciona de manera correcta**, el asunto aquí es que cuando este mismo procedimiento se ejecuta en el **servidor productivo retorna este error**:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): La conversión del tipo de datos nvarchar en datetime produjo un valor fuera de intervalo.
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryHasMoreRows(Boolean& moreRows)
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadInternal(Boolean setTimeout, Boolean& more)
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.Read()

**Implementación del calendario**:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {

        height: 800,
        plugins: ['interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid'],
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
        },
        eventClick: function(info) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Visitors/Edit',
                data: { id: info.event.id, from: 'Calendar' },
                contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function(response) {
                    $("#content-modal").html(response);
                    $("#modalEditVisit").modal("show");
                },
                error: function(xhr, status) {
                    console.log('Disculpe, existió un problema' + JSON.stringify(xhr));
                },
                complete: function(xhr, status) {
                    console.log('Petición realizada');
                }
            });
        },
        eventSources: [
            {
                url: '/Visitors/GetVisitors',
                type: 'POST',
                data: function() {
                    var fecha = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
                    return {
                        month: fecha.getMonth() + 1,
                        year: fecha.getFullYear()
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
        selectable: true,
        selectMirror: true,
        eventRender: function(info) {
            console.log(info.event);
            $(info.el).tooltip({
                title: "Proveedor: " + info.event.title + "<br>Hora: " + moment(info.event.start).format("HH:mm") + " - " + moment(info.event.end).format("HH:mm") + "<br>Área: " + info.event.extendedProps.area,
                placement: "top",
                trigger: "hover",
                container: "body",
                html: true
            });
           
        },
        editable: false,
        eventLimit: 6, // allow "more" link when too many events
        locale: 'es',

    });

    calendar.render();

});
```

Cabe mencionar que los programas son los mismos en ambos servidores, por lo que pienso que el programa está del lado de SQL Server, quizá algo que ver con la configuración regional.

Comment: Si es un problema regional podrías intentar setear el formato de la fecha con SET DATEFORMAT 'tu formato entre '

Comment: Por eso es mala idea almacenar fechas y tiempo en cadenas. Siempre se deben manejar con el tipo de dato adecuado. En caso de que no sea posible, se deben utilizar formatos que no dependan de la configuración regional.

Comment: En mi experiencia ese problema también se produce cuando en el servidor hay una fecha almacenada que no corresponde, ya sea un 31 de abril o similar, podrías pasar tu procedimiento a consulta y verificar directo en la base a ver donde se cae.

Comment: Los dos servidores no son iguales (algo muy malo) y tienen seteado distintos configuraciones regionales (algo peor)... y por eso, tenes todos esos problemas...

Comment: Así es, tienen razón, es un grave error crear servidores con distintas configuraciones de región

Answer (score 0):

**El problema sí es debido a configuraciones de región**, por ejemplo, si se utilizaba el método *SELECT ISDATE('2023-03-15')*, en el servidor de prueba retorna '1', pero en el servidor productivo '0'. Una solución que encontré para la conversión y concatenación del procedimiento almacenado fue el siguiente:

```html
SELECT
    v.Id,
    v.NombreVisitante,
    v.NombreEmpresa,
    v.MotivoVisita,
    CONVERT(DATETIME, v.Fecha + ' ' + v.HoraIngreso, 120) AS HoraIngreso,
    CONVERT(DATETIME, v.Fecha + ' ' + v.HoraSalida, 120) AS HoraSalida,
    CONCAT(e.Nombre, ' ', e.Apellidos) AS Empleado, 
    a.Nombre as Area,
    v.EstatusID
FROM Visitas v
INNER JOIN Empleados e
    ON v.EmpleadoID = e.Id
INNER JOIN Areas a
    ON v.AreaID = a.Id
WHERE 
    v.EstatusID = 100 
    AND v.Fecha >= @FechaInicio
    AND v.Fecha <= @FechaFin
```

**Haciendo uso de la función 'convert'** para asegurarse de que el valor resultante esté en un **formato estándar** que **no depende de la configuración regional** del servidor.